# Error when opening terminal-plus in atom

Tags: visual-c++, terminal, atom-editor

I am using [Atom](http://atom.io) as my editor.I also found a great package that opens up a terminal window inside Atom. However, when I open the terminal I get this error:

[image]

I notified the author of the package about this and he said that another program may be using winpty - possibly the antivirus. I am using Windows but don't have an antivirus.

Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried troubleshooting using a myriad of ways but the package seems broken for quite a number of people as well. The only solution I found was to utilize a package that was forked from the original terminal-plus called platformio-atom-ide-terminal
It can be found here: https://github.com/platformio/platformio-atom-ide-terminal

I learnt about it here: https://github.com/jeremyramin/terminal-plus/issues/201